# Algorithm to find the optimal way of covering a plane with colored rectangles

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that I open up MS Paint, draw a bunch of solid rectangles, save it as a png, and give it to you:

[image]

Now you have to find out how I drew these rectangles. For this image, your algorithm would generate instructions like,

1. Draw the green rectangle (filling up the entire space)
2. Draw the pink rectangle
3. Draw the yellow rectangle
4. Draw the blue rectangle

Or in other words, given an image, I want to generate it using the **fewest rectangle commands** as possible. A rectangle command draws a solid rectangle given its position, length, width, and color. How can I approach this problem?

The algorithm should be robust enough to process images not only drawn by placing rectangles, but also **complex images like photographs**.

Comment: Yea somehow I think DP would work except I can't figure out the details of how exactly to do it

Comment: DP could be a lot of things. What language you choosing?

Comment: The last sentence makes me think that there is a bigger picture. What is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: Trying to write a program that generates a program that draws images. Right now I have pixel(0,0,red), etc, so I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it.

Algorithms should be non language specific.

Comment: A clever algorithm for handling rectangles that aren't ever skewed would be infinitely simpler than one that could handle photos.  With a simple geometric shape like a rectangle maybe you can filter for color and count the number of sides to the resulting shape.  Calculate the length and width based on the bounds of the colored region and build the rectangles starting with the color with the most sides.  You couldn't do that with a photo, though...

Comment: Algorithm for your test image will be trivial. To find boundaries you simply need to calculate bounding box for each color. It is extremely simple and can be done in one pass for all shapes. But it won't work for photos. In fact, the simplest solution for photos would be to make one rectangle per pixel. If you don't like that, then you'll have to use genetic algorithms, which don't qualify because of insane number of required rectangle operations. Also, all solutions I can think of will choke on photographs.

Comment: I'd recommend to forget about "fewest rectangle commands" and stick with genetic algorithms or something like that. http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/ Also, it is obvious that there will be no single perfect solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to find the intersection of two figures, at any point where they intersect find which one is visible. For that point that will give you which one is on top.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably well aware of this, but I'm pretty sure that even with 2 colors this problem is NP-complete.  See the section on orthogonal polygons [here](http://www.cs.usask.ca/~keil/chap.ps).  The covering problems that they look at are similar, but not exactly the same.

Heuristically I suspect that looking for large monochromatic rectangles will not get  you too far from optimal.  Once you have done that try to merge adjoining rectangles of the same color by moving a mutually adjacent different colored rectangle forward in the z order.

Answer (score 1):

It's a multi-step process.

Start with these lists:  R and S.  R is the rectangles (the rectangle draws it uses to build the final image, in order).  S is the section (each area of like-colored pixels).

1) Detect any "Perfect" shapes; any rectangle whose color is found NO WHERE EXCEPT that rectangle.  There must be at least 1, since the last rectangle could not have been overlapped.
Add it to the END of R.

2) Continue (1) until no perfect shapes are left.

3) The next part is tricky.  For each section: if that section plus some collective part of all of the rectangles in R, forms a perfect rectangle, insert that rectangle to the beginning of the list, before all other existing rectangles in R.

4) Repeat (3) until there are no more.

Then you're done.

Comment: How do you do step 3 without exponential blowup? You're kinda glossing over the hard part of the algorithm. ;-)

Comment: It's not as hard as you'd think, although it does slow down a bit here. Think of it like this:  You need to find some point on the section which is either TL, BL, BR, or TR. (Bottom/Top, Left/Right).  Then, the possible corners of the entire rectangle lie in some region so that none of the shape is left out, and none of the shape enters non-drawn sections of the image.  There is *some* blowup, but it isn't quite exponential, and in the case it is, it reverts to 0 after each section is drawn or not drawn, so it doesn't become too large.